# Limit composite primary key to only one record as "not deleted" (where multiple "deleted" records do not invoke constraint)

Tags: postgresql, constraints, delete-row

Want to use a composite primary key so as to limit only one record available for prod.

Table: `user_id text, well_id text, deleted int, [other attributes]`

Proposed primary key: `(user_id, well_id, deleted)`

Uniqueness here is only really related to one record that is a unique combination: `user_id + well_id + deleted = 0 ...`

In other words, could have multiple records where `user_id + well_id + deleted = 1` (deleted value is just a deleted marker)? Right now, I am thinking of just defining that the `deleted` marker represents "deleted" when it is > 0, so I could just increment for all deleted records. But I thought that someone probably has a better idea.

Comment: Why do you need to reuse the IDs?

Comment: Can’t be done. Create a separate table for historic records and store them there instead.

Comment: @stickybit - need to resue ids b/c its a particular user and a particular well.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve uniqueness with a immutable criteria which is `deleted = 0` in your case.

Here is the sample setup;

```
create table table1 (
  id serial primary key,
  user_id text, 
  well_id text, 
  deleted int
);

-- the index is unique only for the records which have deleted = 0 
create unique index on table1 (user_id, well_id) where deleted = 0; 
 
insert into table1 (user_id, well_id, deleted) values ('user1', 'well1', 0);
insert into table1 (user_id, well_id, deleted) values ('user1', 'well1', 1);
-- this statement doesn't throws error
insert into table1 (user_id, well_id, deleted) values ('user1', 'well1', 1);
insert into table1 (user_id, well_id, deleted) values ('user2', 'well2', 0);

select * from table1;
```

| id | user_id | well_id | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | well1 | 0 |
| 2 | user1 | well1 | 1 |
| 3 | user1 | well1 | 1 |
| 4 | user2 | well2 | 0 |

```
-- Finally, this statement throws an error
insert into table1 (user_id, well_id, deleted) values ('user1', 'well1', 0);  

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table1_user_id_well_id_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, well_id)=(user1, well1) already exists.
```

*db fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9b98792054700a81ae10565b8e7ad449)*

Comment: It would be better to have `deleted` be a `boolean`. But this is the correct solution!

Comment: Thank you @Sahap Asci! This is extremely helpful!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - agree on boolean...but comprimising b/c of dev team preferences.

Comment: "Developer team preferences", hmpf. So if they don't know or don't like a data type, even though it is the proper one, it doesn't get used?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  - good point. making the change to boolean